# How to allow users to enter some data in Google Sheet without actually modifying the content?

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to make a sort of calculator based on a grid, where the user checks different lines/columns and it will calculate some stuff based on what's checked. Perhaps I could do something in HTML/JavaScript but I think the Google Sheet environment is much better. However I don't know whether Google Sheet allows users to individually enter values without actually altering the sheet for other users.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to give specific users permission to edit specific ranges. To do this, select a range, choose "protect range" from context menu, then click "set permissions". You will need to know the email addresses of the users, and with many users this  is going to be a lot of hassle. Also, this doesn't look much like "online calculator".

To collect data from users that can't edit the sheet, one can use a [Google form](https://www.google.com/forms/about/). This is great for letting them enter their data, but then you'll have a problem displaying the result of calculations back.

Conclusion: if you are building an online calculator, Google Sheets is not the right tool.